# Could not execute the TestNG file due to error in xml

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using xml for parameter test I am getting below error while running

> It is strongly recommended to add `<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">` at the top of your file, otherwise     TestNG may fail or not work as expected.

here is my xml file for review

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
    <test name="Test">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="PracticeExample.NewTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear, just write

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

instead of simply

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and the upper warning will go away.

Comment: This gives error message The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your replay I tried this and it works fine

```
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">

  <test name="Test">
   <parameter name = "browser" value="firefox"/>
   <parameter name = "browser" value = "chrome"/>

    <classes>
      <class name="PracticeExample.NewTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```